# How to Extend Rails Admin export function to support join tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model Team and Roster as bellow:

Team
attributes: id, name, address

Roster
attributes: id, name, number

When i export the Team its showing records as bellow:

id, name, address
1, abc1, test1 address1
2, abc2, test2 address2

But I wants to join the table rosters as well, so Ideal result should be like bellow:

id, name, address, roster_name
1, abc1, test1 address1, A1
2, abc2, test2 address2, A2

Is there a way to join tables in rails admin?

I am using the method

```
    export do
      configure :rosters_data do
      end
      fields :id, :name, :address, :rosters_data
    end
```

in Team model i defined the rosters_data method

like

```
    def rosters_data()
      self.rosters.all.pluck(:name)
    end
```

current Model Structure

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rosters
end
class Roster < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
end

but its giving all rosters name in single row
```

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR - Yo need to create proper relations between table objects in order to join the data. All joins are based on relations between objects, and for that you just need to improve your architecture to support such relations.**

1. First of all you need a relation between tables to be setup, and for that you will need either one more table or one more field to add.

   - If you need many to many relation (one Team can be in many Rosters AND one Roster can have many Teams) then you need a relation table:

     ```
           # model setup
           class Team
             has_many :team_rosters
             has_many :rosters, through: :team_rosters
           end

           class Roster
             has_many :team_rosters
             has_many :teams, through: :team_rosters
           end

           # this model should have this fields: :id, :team_id, :roster_id
           class TeamRoster
             belongs_to :team
             belongs_to :roster
           end
     ```
   - If you have only one Team on the Roster or only one roster for the team you just need to add respectively **belongs_to :rooster** and a field **rooster_id** OR **belongs_to :team** and field **team_id**
2. After that you can use those relations to get the data you want.

   - for many_to_many relations:

     ```
           # will output only those roster names that the team is in
           @team.rosters.pluck(:name)
     ```
   - for one to many relations:

     ```
           # will output only one roster name that the team is in
           @team.roster.name
     ```
3. **Wrapup.** In order to join something you need to define relations and then those relations will act as basis for the export. Without proper relations you will not be able to tell which Team belongs where or which Roster has what.

Comment: Hello Allacassar, Thanks for reply, I did setup the relationship same as you suggested but still can not access it in rails admin

Comment: In rails Admin we have the options like 
config.model 'Team' do 
  export do
  end
end
Here i would like to edit it like 
config.model  Team.joins(:rosters) do 
end

Comment: In the rails admin docs there is an example that kinda resembles your issue:
` class Ball < ActiveRecord::Base`
`  validates :name, presence: true`
 ` belongs_to :player`
`  rails_admin do`
`    configure :player do`
`      label 'Owner of this ball: '`
`    end`
 ` end`
`end`

so i believe you can configure your relation in the similar way and it should be visible for the export functionality

Comment: so it possible for it to look like this in the teams model
`configure :rosters do` `end`